# What mistake is the author making (if any) while finding this antiderivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, trigonometry

Find the following antiderivative: $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2-x)(x-1)}}}dx$

**My attempt:**

$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2-x)(x-1)}}}dx$$

$$=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-2-x^2+x}}}dx$$

$$=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2+3x-x^2}}}dx$$

$$=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{-(2-3x+x^2)}}}dx$$

$$=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{-(x^2-3x+2)}}}dx$$

$$=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{-(x^2-3x+{(\frac{3}{2})^2)}-2+(\frac{3}{2})^2}}}dx$$

$$=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{0.5^2-(x-\frac{3}{2})^2}}}dx$$

$$[\text{Let $x-\frac{3}{2}=u$}\\ \therefore du=dx]$$

$$=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{0.5^2-u^2}}}dx$$

$$[\text{Formula:}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}}dx=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C, |x|<a]$$

$$=\arcsin\left(\frac{u}{0.5}\right)+C$$

$$=\arcsin\left(\frac{x-\frac{3}{2}}{0.5}\right)+C$$

$$=\arcsin(2x-3)+C$$

My work is correct. I know this because integral-calculator [agrees](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B%282-x%29%28x-1%29%7D%7D) with me (after going to the link, click on "Go!". For steps, click on "Show steps").

However, my book did this math in a different way:

**My book's attempt:**

$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2-x)(x-1)}}}dx$$

$$[\text{Let}\ x-1=u^2,dx=2udu,x=u^2+1,2-x=1-u^2]$$

$$=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)(u^2)}}}2udu$$

$$=\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)}u}}2udu$$

$$=2\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-u^2)}}}du$$

$$[\text{Formula:}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}}dx=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C, |x|<a]$$

$$=2\arcsin(u)+C$$

$$=2\arcsin(x-1)+C$$

**Comments:**

This is the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rols94nxos). From the graph, it doesn't look like the book's answer differs only by a constant from my answer. So, is it wrong? If it is wrong, what mistakes did it make?

Comment: The very last equality looks dodgy to me, $u\ne x-1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yeah you're right! How did I miss that!? If you post this as an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: Better: keep your post, but include details of the book (author, title, chapter, exercise number) so others here can be warned.

Comment: Yes. Since—as observed by [Jyrki](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274266/isnt-my-book-wrongly-equating-frac-frac-sin2x-cos2x-sin-x-cos-x-fra?rq=1#comment8909602_4274266) and [myself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370628/isnt-my-book-making-a-slight-mistake-while-finding-the-antiderivative-here#comment9131112_4370628)—many of your Questions are about this particular textbook's routine errors (and even typos), I think the details requested by @JohnBentin are pertinent (whether or not you opt to retain this Question).

Comment: The last expression should be $2\arcsin(\sqrt{x-1})+C$ and then everything is OK.

Comment: @JohnBentin It's a relatively unknown Bangladeshi book, so I don't think people read this book that much.

Comment: P.S. I prefer your substitution $\displaystyle u=x-\frac32$ to your book's $u^2=x-1.$ In the 3rd and final line (had it been correct) of their working, the tacit understanding is that the substitution's full specification is $[u^2{=}x{-}1$ (**u≥0**)], which can alternatively be written as $u=\sqrt{x-1}$ (i.e., as an explicit instead of an implicit substitution).

Comment: Of course, there is another well-known method to overcome this integral. In that form, the answer would be $-2\arctan\Big(\dfrac{\sqrt{-x^2+3x-2}}{x-2}\Big)+C$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very last equality looks dodgy to me, $u\ne x-1$.

Comment: I rather wish I could delete this.